# Recording Coordinates in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm using pygame and am wondering this:
You push button X to blit an image onto the surface at (x,y). You then move your selector to a new coordinate (xnew, ynew) and hit button X to blit another image at (xnew, ynew) How can I save each coordinate that an image is blitted at for later reference?

Answer (score 1):

Just... add them to a list?

```
blit_spots = []

# ...later on...
blit_spots.append((x, y))
```

Comment: `if (newx, newy) in blit_spots:` (though if membership is what you're wanting to check, you might want to make `blit_spots` a `set` instead and use `blit_spots.add()`)

Comment: So after I do that, how can I go back and check coordinates against those? e.g button X blits imageA at (x,y). If cursor is at (x,y) AGAIN then button X blits imageB at (x,y), but if the cursor is not at (x, y) then button X blits imageA.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it! Using a loop that checks each coordinate using indices of lists, etc.